# Allocating memory and reinterpreting pointer using new in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, memory

I want to allocate memory for n T objects by allocating n * sizeof(T) bytes and get a pointer using new. What's wrong in the following code?

```
template <class T>
void foo(size_t n, const T& value)
{
    T* buffer = reinterpret_cast<T*>(new char[n * sizeof(T)]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        buffer[i] = value;
        std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
}
```

If i do `foo<int>(n, int());`, but if I call `foo<std::string>(n, std::string());` i get segmentation fault.

Comment: you can't reinterpret random memory to a string

Comment: T* buffer = new T[n];  or better yet, use vector.  as it is, you're leaking memory.

Comment: @ethang, ye that would obviously solve the issue, but it would call default initializer for T n times, and I just wanted a way to avoid it.

Comment: if you use vector, you can specify default value.  internally, it calls placement new for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an object in the memory, not just reinterpret the uninitialised bytes as an object. For `int`, you'll get away with it, since assignment will just overwrite whatever's there. `std::string` will (probably) contain an invalid pointer and size, and will think that these refer to data that it's supposed to delete or replace with the assigned value; hence the crash.

To create an object in pre-allocated memory, use placement-new instead of assignment:

```
new(&buffer[i]) T(value);
```

When you've finished with an object, you'll have to call its destructor yourself before deallocating the memory:

```
buffer[i].~T();
```

You could avoid this error-prone dance with `std::vector<T> buffer(n, value);` which does all this behind the scenes without troubling you about it.

Comment: Ah, well, obviously I forgot there's some garbage in there, so the assignment doesn't work as opposed to the placement new. Cool, thank you!